# Can you make an empty sub area change from horizontal to vertical?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

I created a level in Super Mario Maker 2, and now I want to make a sub area. When I went in, I made it horizontal. Is there a way to convert it to vertical, while keeping the blocks in the overworld?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but not while leaving the blocks in the sub-area. If you tap on the button in the bottom-right of the screen in the sub-area that looks like a shopping cart (the one to scroll through the sub-area, switch areas, edit the length of the area, etc.) you’ll see an option to switch orientation (the button looks like an arrow), but doing so will reset the sub-area.